# How do I set the health-check URL on an Elastic Beanstalk instance in a AWS CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that starts an Elastic Beanstalk service. I want to set the health-check URL to `/health` in the template.

What is the convention for this in JSON?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You  need to set the `OptionSettings` property of the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`:

For example:

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
   "Properties" : {
      "ApplicationName" : { "Ref" : "sampleApplication" },
      "Description" :  "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running PHP Sample Application",
      "VersionLabel" : "Initial Version",
      "OptionSettings" : [ 
            {
               "Namespace" : "elasticbeanstalk:application",
               "OptionName" : "Application Healthcheck URL",
               "Value" : "/health"
            }         
      ],      
      "TemplateName" : "DefaultConfiguration",
   }
}
```

In this example, the option `Application Healthcheck URL` is set to `/health`

For more information see:

1. [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-optionsettings)
2. [Configuration Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com//elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_ConfigurationOptionSetting.html)
3. [ConfigurationOptionSettings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com//elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_ConfigurationOptionSetting.html)

Comment: this isn't enough, I have been doing the equivalent for a while now and just got hurt by this. it adds a health check on the LB, yes, but not on individual instances. so instance will still report as healthy and won't be kicked out

Comment: The purpose of the health check url is to check each instance and remove them from the ELB if they fail to respond. Are you seeing different behavior? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html for more information.

Comment: they are not being removed from the ELB, if the HealthCheckType is set to EC2 instead of ELB ...

Answer (score 7):

I added below config under the .ebextension directory

example:

```
option_settings:
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup.aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    HealthCheckPath: /health
```

Answer (score 5):

Rodrigo's answer is good but incomplete.

You also need to modify the health_check_type to ELB, otherwise, when your web application process crash, but your EC2 instead remains healthy, the node won't get replaced.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html

this is the format I am using

```
$ cat .ebextensions/0090_healthcheckurl.config 
Resources:
   AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
     Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
     Properties:
       HealthCheckType: "ELB"
       HealthCheckGracePeriod: "600"
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name:  Application Healthcheck URL
    value:  /_status
```

Comment: Warning: it only works for a classic load balancer. For an application load balancer, option_name  Application Healthcheck URL does not work, the process ALB HealthCheckPath must be used. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html or
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb-shared.html

Answer (score 0):

I you are using an Application load balancer use aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default

```
 {
           "Namespace" : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
           "OptionName" : "HealthCheckPath",
           "Value" : "/elb-status"
        }
```

my complete configuration

```
    "environmentConfigurationTemplate": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate",
  "DependsOn": "ebApplication",
  "Properties": {
    "ApplicationName": {
      "Ref": "ebApplication"
    },
    "Description": "Empower Environment Configuration",
    "EnvironmentId": "",
    "SolutionStackName": {
      "Ref": "Platform"
    },
    "OptionSettings": [
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
        "OptionName": "VPCId",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "VPCId"
        }
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
        "OptionName": "Subnets",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "Subnet"
        }
      },

      {
        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
        "OptionName": "ELBSubnets",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "Subnet"
        }
      },
                {
        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
        "OptionName": "InstanceType",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        }
      },
                {
        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
        "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
        "Value": "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
        "OptionName": "MinSize",
        "Value": "1"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
        "OptionName": "MaxSize",
        "Value": "4"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
        "OptionName": "LoadBalancerType",
        "Value": "application"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy",
        "OptionName": "ProxyServer",
        "Value": "none"
      },
      {
        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
        "OptionName": "FLASK_CONFIGURATION",
        "Value":  {
          "Ref": "Environment"
        }
      },
       {
           "Namespace" : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
           "OptionName" : "HealthCheckPath",
           "Value" : "/elb-status"
        }
    ]
  }
},
```